# facing compatability issues with seleniumwebdriver 2.48 and chromedriver2.9

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using:

1. Selenium Webdriver 2.48 (through Maven dependency).
2. chromedriver_win32.exe (2.27).
3. Java.
4. Latest Updated versions of
   Browsers(chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit), firefox 50.1.0)

when I try driver.get(ÜRL)

It opens up browser but doesn't open the URL.

Getting Error Message .

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 45057
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DHGCEEC', ip: '192.168.1.106', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at pageObjects.Login.main(Login.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DHGCEEC', ip: '192.168.1.106', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Chrome Driver v2.25. and set full path of driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Stuff\\Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. How did you know that chrome driver v2.25 would be compatible? Is there any compatibility chart somewhere? if there is, please post it here .

Comment: if it helps. I found this link but it is not complete.  https://engineering.naukri.com/2015/10/selenium-webdriver-compatibility/     
if anyone finds complete compatibility chart post it here.

Comment: I didn't find any chart also. I faced same issue.